# Python/Shell Script - Merging 2 rows of a CSV file where Address column has 'New Line' character

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file, which contains couple of columns. For Example :

```
FName,LName,Address1,City,Country,Phone,Email
Matt,Shew,"503, Avenue Park",Auckland,NZ,19809224478,matt@xxx.com
Patt,Smith,"503, Baker Street
Mickey Park
Suite 510",Austraila,AZ,19807824478,patt@xxx.com
Doug,Stew,"12, Main St. 
21st Lane 
Suit 290",Chicago,US,19809224478,doug@xxx.com
Henry,Mark,"88, Washington Park",NY,US,19809224478,matt@xxx.com
```

In excel it looks something likes this : [image: Sample Image]

It's a usual human tendency to feed/copy-paste address in the particular manner, usually sometimes people copy their signature and paste it to the Address column which creates such situation.

I have tried reading this using Python CSV module and it looks like that python doesn't distinguish between the '\n' Newline between the field values and the end of line.
My code :

```
import csv
with open(file_path, 'r') as f_obj:
    input_data = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

The output looks somethings like this :

```
{'City': 'Auckland', 'Address1': '503, Avenue Park', 'LName': 'Shew', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Matt', 'Country': 'NZ', 'Email': 'matt@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'Austraila', 'Address1': '503, Baker Street\nMickey Park\nSuite 510', 'LName': 'Smith', 'Phone': '19807824478', 'FName': 'Patt', 'Country': 'AZ', 'Email': 'patt@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'Chicago', 'Address1': '12, Main St. \n21st Lane \nSuit 290', 'LName': 'Stew', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Doug', 'Country': 'US', 'Email': 'doug@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'NY', 'Address1': '88, Washington Park', 'LName': 'Mark', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Henry', 'Country': 'US', 'Email': 'matt@xxx.com'}
```

I just wanted to write the same content to a file where all the values for a *`Address1`* **`keys`** should not have '\n' character and looks like :

```
{'City': 'Auckland', 'Address1': '503, Avenue Park', 'LName': 'Shew', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Matt', 'Country': 'NZ', 'Email': 'matt@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'Austraila', 'Address1': '503, Baker Street Mickey Park Suite 510', 'LName': 'Smith', 'Phone': '19807824478', 'FName': 'Patt', 'Country': 'AZ', 'Email': 'patt@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'Chicago', 'Address1': '12, Main St. 21st Lane Suit 290', 'LName': 'Stew', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Doug', 'Country': 'US', 'Email': 'doug@xxx.com'}
{'City': 'NY', 'Address1': '88, Washington Park', 'LName': 'Mark', 'Phone': '19809224478', 'FName': 'Henry', 'Country': 'US', 'Email': 'matt@xxx.com'}
```

Any suggestions guys ???

PS:
I have more than 100K such records in my csv file !!!

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the `print row` with a dict comprehsion that replaces newlines in the values:

```
row = {k: v.replace('\n', ' ') for k, v in row.iteritems()}
print row
```

Comment: Hey @Jkdc - Do you have any optimized solution, complexity will go to O(n square) and more over I have files with 100K+ records ?

Comment: @Avi I'm not aware of any more optimal way, you might have better response by replacing the newlines in the file before passing it into CSV's dictreader, but I doubt it would be any significant gain.

Comment: No worries !! As of now thanks for the solution - this might give me an intermediate way